# magento change block not working properly

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7

on my product page I have added related product on right sidebar.

there are other block also displayed on sidebar these are

-related product
-recently viewed product
-mycart
-paypal logo

Now I want related product to get displayed after mycart and paypal logo, right now it is displayed on top of right bar

I have used before and after but that is not working.

These is my code

paypal.xml

```
<reference name="right">
        <block type="paypal/logo" name="paypal.partner.right.logo" after="cart_sidebar" template="paypal/partner/logo.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

catalog.xml

```
<reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" after="paypal.partner.right.logo" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

checkout.xml

```
<reference name="right">
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
            </block>
        </block>
```

how can I put mycart and paypal logo on top of right bar.

Comment: <reference name="right">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" after="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
</reference>

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create or update your local.xml file IF you do not have a local.xml file you can create one in

app->frontend->[Package Name]->[Theme Name]->layout->local.xml

Once this is created you can copy exactly what I have in this post into that file for a start of how to use one.

DO ALL UPDATES THROUGH A LOCAL.XML file not through catalog.xml or checkout.xml !! This will make upgrades significantly easier later down the road. Additionally, you will be able to quickly see all changes you have made to your site in one file. This way I can see what you are actually updating.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="right">
            <!-- <action method="unsetChild"><alias>catalog.product.related</alias></action> -->
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" after="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

If you end up with two try uncommenting my action method..  I can't remember if you have to declare it in separate reference or within there because I didn't test this but give it a try